# Why do SignTool/Authenticode Message Digests not match the direct hash of the file?

Tags: hash

I'm attempting to validate an Authenticode signature (generated by `signtool /fd SHA256 /f <code signing PFX> /p <PFX password> test.exe`), and I've run into an issue that I've narrowed down to a single point of confusion.

For the command above, if I hash test.exe before running the signing operation, for example using `Get-FileHash test.exe` in Powershell, I get a SHA256 hash of the file. But after signing the file, inspecting the signature in windows (Properties -> Digital Signatures -> Details -> Advanced) shows a "Message Digest" value which is entirely different from the hash of test.exe as calculated before signing.

Windows reports this signature as valid, so there is clearly a consistent understanding of "Message Digest" that isn't the one I have in my head (hash of the raw file contents, excluding signature). Can somebody please explain to me what Message Digest means in this context, and how it differs from a regular hashing operation?

Comment: I guess the signature is attached to the file, which changes the outcome of the hash applied to it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - the signature is definitely attached to the file and does change the hash, but I wasn't expecting the raw hash of the file after signing to stay the same or match the Message Digest field inside the signature (that would require finding a very specific collision every time). What I expect to see is pre-signing hash == Message Digest inside the signature properties.

Comment: There's no particular reason why the message digest shouldn't include some additional meta information. It probably comes down to the exact specification of the tool you're using. But that I would think is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting that the hash that is produced is always over the complete file. This is not correct. Authenticode uses the Cryptographic Message Syntax - a container format - to embed the content and the signature. This ensures that the Authenticode signature is using the hash of the original data (+ other signed attributes). The Authenticode format is specified [here](https://www.symbolcrash.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Authenticode_PE-1.pdf).

To quote:

> A PKCS#7 `SignedDatastructure` contains the PE file's hash value, a signature created by the software publisher’s private key, and the X.509 v3 certificates that bind the software publisher’s signing key to a legal entity. A PKCS#7 `SignedDatastructure` can optionally contain:
>
> - A description of the software publisher.
> - The software publisher's URL.
> - An Authenticode timestamp.

Note that Microsoft keeps interchanging the name of the standard with the name of the structure that it defines: PKCS#7 is the standard that defines the Cryptographic Message Syntax.

Unfortunately, going through all the steps of "Calculating the PE Image Hash" is a bit too much for this answer; if you plan to do this programmatically you could ask questions about it on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'll never get over the stupidity of creating a class called `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to implement PBKDF2

Comment: Oh! I absolutely had not made the connection between Authenticode and PKCS#7 in the documentation of SignTool. I knew it was possible to output signatures as PKCS#7, but not that they always were behind the scenes embedded in files.

I did realise that the hash would produced over the *original* data (not the complete signed file), but not that other signed attributes were included, I'll brush up on RFC 2315 and the Authenticode document you linked. Thank you.

Comment: Fortunately Microsoft at least created that PDF document for us to read. OK, it is full of proprietary structures, but it is at least using a well defined standard and they did try to document it to the best of their abilities. I have to give credit to MS as well instead of just bashing them (which, in my opinion, they often do deserve).